# Standard vs Enterprise Edition SQL Server 2016 SP1 ReadOnly Replica

Tags: sql-server

Preparing 3 layer architecture for the first time (IIS/SQL Server). I would like to add 2 app servers for the very beginning and two machine SQL Server cluster. Have experience with DB Mirror and Log Shipping so far.

From what I have read, DB Mirror is deprecated feature and I would not like to use it. However, if the client purchase SQL Server 2016 SP1 Standard Edition license the second(only) replica is not read only, i.e. not accessible??

I would like to use the secondary replica for read only queries(to offload the primary). I am OK with few seconds (even a minute) delay in data synchronization,  however I would like to always have response from secondary replica. If I understood correctly there is no way to accomplish this with Basic 2 node AOAG??

Log Shipping probably will not be an option since backup/copy/restore (apply logical logs) sequence does not have much sense in a minute interval?
If I am mixing HA features with performance features I may even add additional server for RO purposes, as long as I achieve what we need.(so one replica serves as HA feature and the other "replication of some type" serves as RO instance) I also have a need to replicate the DB to remote location, but I think that log shipping will do the job here(I guess there is no limit on one instance serving both AOAG and log shipping in the same time, please share any experience)

Furthermore I would like to ask, what response client receives while applying logical logs or REDO thread on the secondary, ERROR or delay (for both log shipping and AOAG?

We can put some timeout(wait delay) on the client side but  I think that it will under perform reading from the RW instance.

**Question:**

So long story short is there any way that I can achieve something like "continuous transaction log restore" to an instance that will be always available for READS when using standard edition of the software?

Thank you.
Aleksandar

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. As this is a Database Administration question, it belongs on the [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) page.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a snapshot of the secondary just like mirroring..there are some rules which you need to follow,below are them

1.The replica role must be either PRIMARY or SECONDARY, not in the RESOLVING state.

Also Microsoft states below

> Some Always On availability groups conditions cause both the source database and its database snapshots to be restarted, temporarily disconnecting users. These conditions are as follows:
>
> The primary replica changes roles, whether because the current primary replica goes off line and comes back online on the same server instance or because the availability group fails over.
>
> The database enters the secondary role.
>
> If the availability replica that hosts database snapshots is failed over, the database snapshots remain on the server instance where they were created. Users can continue to use the snapshots after the failover.If performance is a concern in your environment, we recommend that you create database snapshots only on secondary databases that are hosted by a secondary replica that is configured for manual failover mode. If you ever manually fail over the availability group to this secondary replica, you can create a new set of database snapshots on another secondary replica, redirect clients to the new database snapshots, and drop all of the database snapshots from the now primary databases.

References used :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/database-snapshots-with-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way that I can achieve something like "continuous transaction log restore" to an instance that will be always available for READS when using standard edition of the software?

Standard Edition supports Transactional Replication, which can be used to create a near-real-time readable (logical) replica of all or part of your primary database.  In TR the log records are read to reconstruct DML statements that are applied to the subscriber, so it's logical, rather than physical replication. Transactional Replication is not normally used for high availability.

> what response client receives while applying logical logs or REDO thread on the secondary, ERROR or delay (for both log shipping and AOAG?

For Log Shipping or Database Snapshots all read clients must be disconnected to roll the replica forward in time.  You can use synonyms to mitigate this at the cost of some complexity, as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2008/08/05/microsoft-sql-server-database-snapshots-and-synonyms/).

For an AlwaysOn Availability Group readable replica, the replica is continuously readable as log records are applied.